# Merging points based on coordinates using python (pandas or geopandas)

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have a dataset like:

```
pointID  lat  lon  otherinfo
```

I want to round up the coordinates and aggregate all the points whose coordinates become equal into one single item, and assign it a new name, which would probably be a new dataframe column. The "otherinfo" column must be preserved, meaning that by the end of the operation I will have the same number of rows I had before, but with new IDs based on the rounded coordinates.

How can I achieve this using pandas? Is it any easier if I use geoPandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have columns for coodinates (lat and lon), you can do for example (rounding to 2 decimal numbers):

```
df['new_id'] = df.groupby([df.lat.round(2), df.lon.round(2)]).ngroup()
```

The [`ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) method on the groupby gives for each original row to which group it belongs, so in fact gives you a new unique ID based on rounded lat/lon.

Comment: This works, thanks! I didn't know the `ngroup` method. The only thing I don't understand is why I have a "-1" group. I mean, from the reference is clear that groups will be labeled from 0 to n-1, where n is the number of groups; still, I have a "-1" group.

Comment: That's typically a sign that you've got a NaN causing problems.  Do you have one?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that as well. But still, it would be good to document this better, so @sato feel free to open an issue or PR about this on the pandas issue tracker.

Comment: Actually I don't have any NaN. I will follow joris advice asap, meanwhile I simply did `df['new_id'] = df.groupby([df.lat.round(2), df.lon.round(2)]).ngroup()+1` as a temporary workaround.